# How to add carousel view inside custom UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icarousel

I am having difficulties to add carousel view in a table cell view.
I want the carousel to look like this:

[image]

It is a table cell with a profile picture on the left and a carousel view with multiple images on the right.
Please help me how to do this.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Create a subclass for UITableViewCell (i.e.) custom cell, refer this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview  .Do more search before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not a big problem if you now know how to add a carousel view.

In ViewController that is your TableView delegate in method

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

just add "if" state to define which type should cell have and do all other stuff there. Like this

```
 if (indexPath.row == 0) {
 NSString *labelCellIdentifier = @"CellWithLabelIdentifier";
 CellWithLabel *cell == (CellWithLabel *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:labelCellIdentifier];

 //do your things

 } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
 NSString *carouselCellIdentifier = @"CellWithCarouselIdentifier";
 CellWithCarousel *cell == (CellWithCarousel *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:carouselCellIdentifier];

 //do your things

 }
```

P.S. remember to put your code in multiple methods wise if this method becomes to big to understand what's going on in your code later